# Shortcut or quickway to copy codes with the same tag in Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tags

Is there a shortcut to copy everything with the same tag in Vscode?

e.g.

```
<h2>Apple</h2>
<p>It's a fruite.</p>
<h2>Banana</h2>
<p>It's also a fruite.</p>
```

Goal: Copy all codes within h2 tag.

Result:

```
 <h2>Apple</h2>
 <h2>Banana</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

- select `<h2>`
- use menu **Select** ? **Select All Occurrences**
- `ArrowRight`
- `ArrowLeft`
- use command `Emmet: Balance (outward)`
- `Ctrl+C`
- `Esc`
- Go to the new location
- `Ctrl+V`

Answer (score 0):

1. Select `<h2>`
2. Press `Ctrl` + `D`
3. Press `Shift` + `End`
4. Press `Ctrl` + `C`
5. Put the cursor wherever you want to paste the code
6. Press `Ctrl` + `V`

Answer (score 0):

- Position you cursor under some the desired tag, and press `Ctrl+d`.
- Use `Ctrl+shift+L`.
- Press some arrow key once. for example right arrow.
- Remove the selected lines using `Ctrl+x`.
- Undo the cut operation by pressing `Ctrl+z`.

Reinsert the previously cut lines at the desired spot.[image]